# Wordpress already Installed in root Directory and I have also installed wordpress in subdirectory, But the problem is subdirectory URL is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Wordpress already Installed in root Directory and I have also installed wordpress in subdirectory, But the problem is subdirectory URL is not working. It always give 404 error

> Root
>
> https://boochcraft.com/
>
> Subdirectory URL
>
> https://boochcraft.com/shop

**Root Directory .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Sub-directory .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the sub-directory ".htaccess" to be the same as the original one, no need to prefix your Rewrite rules with "./shop". Then just continue to "boochcraft.com/shop" to continue setup of the 2nd WP with a separate database. If in any case you already have the "boochcraft.com/shop" WP setup, go the corresponding database in the "wp_options" table and change "home" and "site_url" values to "boochcraft.com/shop".

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress rewriting system messes with custom sub-directories.
While you could change the rules in the htaccess, I'd advice you to **use a sub-domain instead of a sub directory**.

So it would be https://shop.boochcraft.com.

It's usually possible with all main hosting providers. Just install your wordpress in a different folder on the FTP (shop instead of www on the root), and if you're limited to 1 database, don't forget to **change the prefix** of the shop-wordpress so your two installs don't mix up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove /shop from the last rule in .htaccess file in the sub-directory (RewriteBase stays as before).

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```